# Count the number of occurrences of each fill color over an arbitrary range of cell?

Tags: excel, vba

My attempt is below, but it is totally off base, and I am new to VBA macros. I have only been able to write the most rudimentary type of functions.

Function lbrHrsTot(Rng As Range) As String
Dim R As Long
Dim G As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim Re As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim S As Long

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Rng
    If Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        R = R + 1
    ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
        G = G + 1
    ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then
        B = B + 1
    ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166) Then
        S = S + 1
    ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
        Y = Y + 1
    ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0) Then
        Re = Re + 1
    End If
Next Cell

lbrHrsTot = "Red " & R & " Green " & G & " Blue " & B & " Silver " & S & " Yellow " & Y & " Dark Red " & R
```

End Function

[function result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XL8J.jpg)

Comment: You're always checking `Rng.Interior.Color`... not the individual cells in `Rng`.

Comment: First of all you should not use color to transport information. Always use data/values to transport information and colors only for displaying purpose so you can see it more easily. Color is very hard to process for Excel and super slow, while data/values are much faster. Consider if you can change your approach to data.

Comment: Can you elaborate and offer a correction? I don't understand.

Comment: I would definitely prefer to not use colors, but my superiors are stuck on the idea, so I am forced to do so.

Comment: But how are the colors applied to the sheet? Manually or e.g. by conditional formatting?

Comment: They are regrettable applied manually :/

Comment: If you can correspond each color to a value and put that value into the cell instead of the color and use conditional formatting to still have that color generated automatically. This ways your superiors see their colors and the sheet can be processed fast.

Comment: I would do that. Trouble is the categorization is not something that can be automated due to the complexity of the data. I am tracking labor hour activity in half-hour intervals over 12 hour shifts for operators on a refinery, and their work is wildly variable.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that could work.
Loop through each `Cell` in the `Rng` and check its color.

```
Function lbrHrsTot(Rng As Range) As String
    Dim R As Long
    Dim G As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim Re As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim S As Long

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            R = R + 1
        ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) Then
            G = G + 1
        ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then
            B = B + 1
        ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166) Then
            S = S + 1
        ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) Then
            Y = Y + 1
        ElseIf Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0) Then
            Re = Re + 1
        End If
    Next Cell

    lbrHrsTot = "Red " & R & " Green " & G & " Blue " & B & " Silver " & S & " Yellow " & Y & " Dark Red " & R
End Function
```

Consider using `Select Case` instead of the multiple `If … ElseIf … End If`.

Comment: Thanks for the code! Sadly, it appears to be a near miss.

Comment: I edited my question and put your code in and then a picture of the output. See the link "function result" above.

Comment: Perhaps it's right but it's not accounting for the fact that I have merged cells?

Comment: @MeccaMiles merged cells are evil. Once again you see how bad the idea is because of a bad approach in the beginning you have to do all those workarounds. Fail by design. Try if `For Each Cell In Rng.Resize(ColumnSize:=1)` instead.

Comment: Your code works, I just needed to divide the result by the 9 merged row cells.